# SystemVerilog object creation process

Tags: system-verilog

```
class parent;
int a = 10;
endclass

class child extends parent;
int b = 10;
endclass

module main;
  parent P;
  child C;

  P = new();
  C = new();

  initial begin
    $display("a=%d\n",C.a);
  end
endmodule
```

I tried to run this code using Synopsys VCS. It is giving an error at the object creation after the handle declaration. The error is as follows:

> Error-[SE] Syntax error   Following verilog source has syntax error : 
>   "class.sv", 20: token is '='      P = new();

Comment: The output does not match the code you show. What are you expecting?

Comment: Your edits completely changed the sense of the question so that the answer is no longer an answer to the question and will make no sense to future readers. So, I have rolled them back. If you have another question, please ask it as another question. I have also deleted all the extraneous output from VCS.

Comment: Hi Matthew! All I am expecting is to create a object using the the class handle. If you run the above code it gives error but if you do
parent P = new()
Then it does not give any error. I want to know the reason behind this.

Comment: Hi @K.Piyush, then ask a new question and I will answer it. The idea behind Stack Overflow is that your questions and answers become useful to future Googlers. Conversations like this and edits that completely change the sense of a question are not useful to future Googlers.

Answer (score 1):

Put your constructors inside the `initial` block.